# How can I easily indent a block in any textarea on OS X?

Tags: keyboard, text-editor, shortcut

Are there shortcut keys or another quick way to indent a text block at once in a normal text area on OS X?

So that I can easily turn:

```
[I want this to indent.
For formatting.
It's several lines.]
```

Into:

```
    [I want this to indent.
    For formatting.
    It's several lines.]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to edit text, and for that you need a text editor. There is (easy) native way in OS X to do these kind of text manipulations.

I personally use BBEdit/[TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) for these kind of codings. <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>

You can also use Automator to create a Service and use sed/regex to do the 'hard' lifting: (and bind a keystroke to this Service)

[image: automator]

`sed 's/\(^.*\)/\ \ \ \ \1/g'`:

*sed can be used to edit lines of text. In this line sed globally substitutes a match of 'the beginning of a line and everything that comes after it' with '4 spaces and that match'.*

Comment: What about the Cocoa Text System, couldn't that be used to provide a custom shortcut for an indent command?

Comment: Nice thought, it might be possible to do that, though I have no clue how ;) It is a clean way to do it though.